# Multiple series highstock live chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts, real-time

I already have a realtime live graph with one series working. Just like [this tutorial](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data).

This is my js code

```
<script>
var chart;
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'live-server-data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20;
            chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
            setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
</script>
```

And this is the JSON passed by live-server-data.php

```
[1430687116000,994]
```

How do I make the  js script graph more than one series? My guess is iterate the JSON array passed and add the points for each series, but don't know how to implement that on js, jquery, ajax or whatever it is i have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things:

1) Your server should return more info in that request, for example:

```
[ [1430687116000, 994], [1430687116000, 5], ... , [1430687116000, 11] ]
```

Or better format to provide timestamps just once:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1430687116000,
    "points": [ 994, 5, ... , 11 ]
}
```

2) Now just update all of the series:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php',
    success: function(points) {
        var series = chart.series,
            shift;

        $.each(series, function(i, s) {
            shift = s.data.length > 20;
            s.addPoint(points[i], false, shift);
        });
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);   
        chart.redraw(); 
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Or with a second format for JSON it would be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'live-server-data.php',
    success: function(points) {
        var series = chart.series,
            shift;

        $.each(series, function(i, s) {
            shift = s.data.length > 20;
            s.addPoint([points.timestamp, points.data[i]], false, shift);
        });
        setTimeout(requestData, 1000);   
        chart.redraw(); 
    },
    cache: false
});
```

Comment: Ok, I did the first option, but I still don't get the expected results, take a look to [this screenshot](http://s28.postimg.org/9pnsb2yr1/result.png) and this is [the code](http://s9.postimg.org/lf74i5j0v/code.png) that generates the chart. what am I missing?

Comment: It depends. 1) Do you want to use multiple series? How do you differentiate `Series X` and `Series Y` ? 2) Make sure your data is sorted ascending by x-values (first item in the points' arrays: `[1430687116000, 994]` - > `1430687116000`).